# Use a temporary table for union?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
item_id| attribute_1 | attribute_2 | creation_date
```

I want to build a "filter" search for each attributes.
ex.

```
Attribute 1
  <checkbox> value 1 (x)
  <checkbox> value 2 (x)
  <checkbox> value 3 (x)

Attribute 2
  <checkbox> value 1 (x)
  <checkbox> value 2 (x)
  <checkbox> value 3 (x)
```

Where x = number of products for each attribute value

After some thinking, I found the only way to do this with mysql is with this kind of query (on top of that I need some conditions for the filters, ex. creation_date > "2018-10-10":

```
SELECT 
    `attribute_2` as attribute, COUNT(*) AS counter 
FROM
    TABLENAME
WHERE
    creation_date > "2018-10-10"
GROUP BY
    attribute_2

UNION ALL

SELECT `attribute_1` as attribute, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM
    TABLENAME
WHERE
    creation_date > "2018-10-10"
GROUP BY
    attribute_1
```

So, I am worried about performance.
Do I need to create a temporary table with the creation_date > "2018-10-10" and work on that temporary table?

Will this improve performance?

Do you see other way to write more efficient query for this type of requirement?

Comment: "Do you see other way to write more efficient query for this type of requirement?" Yes incrementing table columns names are suspect and a very good candidate for table normalisation.

Comment: is the *GROUP BY
    attribute_2* in the second query correct ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland can you elaborate more ton incrementing table columns?

Comment: @yeahman - do you know all possible values of Attribute 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen no not without making a query

Comment: @RaymondNijland hmm these are not incrementing column names... it is just an example.. in real life, the columns are more like "color", "size", "manufacturer", etc...

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no other way to query this ... and I think a temporary table is not necessary as I think the first query will be cached my mysql engine... but I am not 100% sure